# Java Matcher Error

Tags: regex

My string:

```
null[00:14.04]I've /n[00:14.11]got /n[00:14.18]a /n[00:14.25]fee- /n[00:15.02]ling /n
```

I am trying to obtain every data between [<--->] brackets. Here's my code.

```
String find = "[(.*?)\\\\]";
Pattern patern = Pattern.compile(find);
Matcher matcher  = patern.matcher(intake);
     while(matcher.find()){
         i++;
         matcher.find(i);
         int start = matcher.start();
         int end = matcher.end();
         String group = matcher.group();
     }
```

The first results are:

```
start = 10
end = 11
group = "."
```

What I wanted was (Counting on my head)

```
start = 4
end = 14
group = [00:14.04]
```

Next is

```
start = 22
end = 32
group = [00:14.11]
```

and so on

What is the correct pattern?

Comment: So you want it to match and return on everything inside of a `[]` bracket, so all the timestamps?  What you say in your "wanting" isn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using wrong escaping. Use this regex:

```
String find = "\\[(.*?)\\]";
```

**EDIT:** Based on your comment:

If you want to capture all items inside square brackets just run your while loop like this:

```
while(matcher.find()) {
    String matched = matcher.group(1);
    System.out.printf("Matched Group: [%s]%n", matched);
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to match all items inside the brackets. Sorry let me update my question.

Comment: @Akyl: This will match string inside square brackets correctly and it will produce **exact** start, end, group values as you're expecting.

Comment: Sorry, you were right I made a mistake on my loop to repeat it's process my bad. Thanks btw.